when i choose fb project to link my flutter app with i see" Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration
when i try to connect flutter with firebase
i type flutterfire configure
and choose a project
and i got asked :
Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'?
what should i write
i tried to write my app package name like 'com.appname.appname_app'
and i got that error
Failed to create Android app for project diera-dev. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
i tried reauth and clean cache and nothing happen

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
